# how install magento2 on ipage or hostgattor server ? please suggest

Tags: magento2

Anybody know the answer please describe .Actually we have installed on wamp server on my localhost but not getting how to install on server.

Comment: Could you describe the specific problems you run into? What did you try so far? What problems/errors did you encounter? Please edit and update your question. With this very small amount of information you are giving now, we are unable to help you.

Answer (score 2):

For that, you have to make sure that the server meets minimum Magento 2 requirements.
For that please check http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/bk-install-guide.html Here all Magento requirements are specified.

You will need to make a zip of the installed folder and upload the zip on the server. Also, make an SQL file of the DB. upload it to the server and unzip it.

Make changes in app/etc/env.php for DB configuration.This will migrate your Magento store.

Thank you